# Reporting a local business for paying their employees well below minimum wage,

Tags: ethics

I want to report a local business, where many of my friends work for $10 an hour, while the minimum wage is currently at $15 an hour -- it has in fact been at $15 an hour for over a year now.

What advice would you offer, before I write to the Department of Labor and possibly to other entities?

Many people, customers and employees, have urged the store owner to pay minimum wage, but he will not budge.  The owner often uses weak excuses and obfuscates, by saying things like, "look at GrubHub, they're doing terribly, because minimum wage is too high a labor cost for them!"

Based on my own observations, I see that this local business is thriving, with many customers in-store, as well as via the multiple delivery apps such as Uber Eats, Postmates, Seamless, etc.

This business is not tip-based either; there are no bartenders, waiters, or waitresses.

Would I be doing the right thing by reporting this?

On the one hand, I feel I should fight for these employees (who often urge me to speak up), and they are often college students, or at-risk individuals, e.g. ex-prisoners.  The store owner, I think, feels that there is no shortage of such vulnerable workers to hire and exploit, and so he doesn't have to change his ways.

On the other hand, me reporting him could have the effect of getting these employees laid off, leaving them worse off and scrambling to find new jobs, which, for the ex-cons in particular, could be very difficult.

Comment: Not your fight, don't stick your nose in into other people's money.

Comment: I had a friend years ago in a similar situation, with the similar quandary.  She preferred the illegal paying job to no job at all, and so I said nothing.

Comment: You say the employees do ask you to speak up?  Is there a reason why they don't do anything themselves?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek, I'm not sure, but perhaps they're scared.  The ones that asked me to speak up are undergrads in college.  IMO, they probably don't feel they have their own voice yet in the working world / haven't found their own voice yet, and so they're not able to self-advocate at that age, I assume ...

Comment: In what State is this? I assume California. Right?

Comment: @stephanbranczyk if it matters, New York City, actually, and in Manhattan.

Comment: You do realize that minimum wage is not universally 15$ in NY?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul [It is $15 in Manhattan](https://www1.nyc.gov/nycbusiness/description/wage-regulations-in-new-york-state)

Comment: We can't tell you whether or not you should report this. I think there might be an on topic question in here like, "How can I help my friends get paid properly?", that wouldn't invalidate existing answers. If you can reword this so you're not asking us to make a choice (or ask our opinion about your choice), I'll cast a re-open vote.

Comment: Wages are grandfathered. If you're making $10 an hour and the minimum goes up to $15, the employer has no obligation to give you a raise to match it. That's just not how minimum wage works. Nothing illegal is happening here.

Comment: @Josh. That is not true of minimum wage. It is true of non-statutory wage increases (you come in at $15, next year a guy comes in at $16, you stay at $15) but everyone must get at least the statutory minimum wage. The increase was phased in, but for NYC it has been $15 for a year for everyone.

Answer (score 6):

Whatever you do, do not do anything without your friends' permission.

I believe your friend has two years to file with the Department of Labor of your State. So that one year of partial wage theft hasn't been lost yet, the Department of Labor can recover it for her, even if it means going after the personal assets of the owner.

Also note, that the Department of Labor can potentially protect your friend from getting fired and other forms of retaliation, but that most likely won't happen if you report it yourself. She has to report this herself, not you. If you report this yourself, you may just get her fired.

At the same time, if she reports this herself, she'll probably be protected, but that might mean her coworkers won't be.

The ideal solution would be to have everyone seek employment elsewhere. Not only it's easier to find a job when you're already employed. But if most of the existing staff is able to get a job elsewhere, the departing staff can take the blame for blowing the whistle and the remaining staff is less likely to be retaliated against.

In the meantime, your friend and her co-workers need to log their work hours and document their work as much as possible.

**With that said, do not trust a word of what I said.** I'm not a lawyer. Plus, I am from San Francisco, not New York City, so for all I know, all of my information could be incorrect. Your friend really needs to contact the Department of Labor of New York.

https://www.labor.ny.gov/workerprotection/laborstandards/workprot/lshmpg.shtm

If she's worried about anonymity. Tell her not to give out her name, nor the name of the business she's working for. If they insist on a name, she can just call herself Jane Doe. And lend her your phone. Because when you call an 800/888 number, there is no way to block caller ID.

She doesn't need to pull the trigger on this yet, but she needs to inform herself. At the very least, she needs to find out what the deadlines are, to ensure maximum wage theft recovery. Plus, she needs to ensure that when the day comes, that she has enough proof for the Department of Labor to want to act on. And while she's at it, she should ask them what can be done to protect any of her remaining co-workers from being retaliated against (but still get them paid what they're owed).

If she isn't satisfied with their answers, she can just hang up the phone and not report anything.

Comment: This is the better answer - it's especially a good point that the friend needs to document their pay.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that because you are not an employee, with proof of substandard pay, that you would not be able to report this anyway.  But you could find out for the employees, what the process would be.

You could call the local/state/district authorities and ask what the process is for reporting a business that pays less than minimum wage.  Let them know that you are not an employee, but want to know what the process would be for an employee, so you can help them in the process of reporting.

Perhaps they will ask for the name of the company and do their own investigation.  Perhaps they will tell you enough so that you can help your friends.

In the meantime, how are your friends paid?  Are taxes being taken out at all, or are they being paid under the table?  Because if taxes are paid, there is stronger proof that they are being paid less than minimum wage.  If they are being paid in cash, the owner can simply claim they are not even employees, and thus it is a false claim.  (And, I'm sure, at that point they will no longer be employees.  Your friends need to be aware that they certainly can lose their job by speaking up, no matter what happens.)